LPC4333 Internal EEPROM Endurance and Wear Levelling
I am trying to understand the the datasheet for the EEPROM Endurance.
I can see that the EEPROM has a minimum of 100K erase/write cycles.
Is this per word, per page or just in total?
The EEPROM has 128 pages x 128 bytes.
I need to write a wear levelling algorithm to give me the maximum endurance. I only need to write 1 word at a time.
So, for example, if I write my word at consecutive locations within a page would this give me 128 * 100K cycles?
Or if I write my word on consecutive pages would this give me 128 * 100K cycles?
Or further If I was to write my word at consecutive locations within a page in consecutive pages would I get 128 * 128 * 100K cycles?
Please can someone advise what would give me the best endurance for a single word that needs to be stored repetitively?
Thanks.

I think on this processor the erase operation can be done on individual words (32bits). From the manual "Partial page writes are allowed, and the EEPROM will only take locations where a word
has been written for the erase/program cycle. Any word in a page can be written in any
order, but every word in the page may only be written once"
